# built-in card reader and webcam stopped working after upgrade

Tags: windows-7, drivers, webcam, sd-card

I have a sony vaio vgn-fz460e and I actually have two problems. One, my mass storage controller is not installed and when I click to apply this fix...it's says mass storage controller doesn't have a driver. I'm clueless as to what to do because I've looked up drivers and apparently I'm overlooking because just about everyone I run across isn't compatible. My sd card reader and built-in webcam has worked before getting my pc repaired from a crash. Now neither works. My webcam says it is workly properly but I can't get it to turn on. I was told maybe I need to turn it on by cmd prompt but I have no clue. Please if possible someone help with one or the other....perferably the sd card reader because my boyfriend uses that the most. I had windows vista but repair guy upgraded it to windows 7 >.< More info needed just let me know. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you checked Sony website and get drivers from their website?

Comment: Specific information is required to help you.  Have you installed the drivers for both devices.  Can you pst a screenshot of the devices in Device Manager and post the screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like your repair guy in upgrading vista to 7 wiped out all of your proprietary sony drivers that came with your computer out of the box. This is usually fixable by downloading the appropriate drivers from the vender's website.

A quick search yields this memory card reader which may be what you're looking for
http://esupport.sony.com/US/perl/swu-download.pl?mdl=VGNFZ460E&upd_id=3380&os_id=28

I would search on that sony website for the rest of the vgn-fz460e drivers.

Comment: I've checked Sony website and for Windows 7 i don't see a memory card reader/writer driver like Vista....will Vista work for 7, I've heard it wouldn't but I'm not very computer savvy when it comes to fixing a computer. As far as the camera driver, under Windows 7 Wecam Campanion Software and some visual effects software, so I'm clueless....unless I'm not looking in the wrong place or just completely slow lol.

Comment: did you click the link in the answer?

Comment: yes i just haven't tried it yet because it says it is for Vista not 7....does it matter?

Comment: would restoring it to factory settings work

Comment: factory restore should work. if you're willing to do that, there's no harm in installing the drivers even tho they say vista. if it doesn't work, restore to factory settings.

Comment: k, well i've tried installing the driver from the link and other vista drivers and they still don't seem to work. so i'm going to keep looking for a solution but if i can't figure out what to do, i will pobably just factory restore it. one more question if i factory restore i should have windows vista back?? because that's what the computer came with right....

Comment: assuming your factory restore is a CD that came with your computer or a partition on your hard drive, it should literally turn your computer to the way it was when you first turned it on, with windows vista installed.